# String[] Input for REST Calls

Tags: json, rest

I am new to REST Programming. I have a requirement to automate the working of an appliance which requires me to login to the appliance, use the auth token and perform other rest calls on the appliance subsequently. I have been able to login and perform routine GET calls and parse the output of the REST calls.

Now, the specification of the REST call that I am unable to understand is as following:

- Call: `PUT /rest/os-deployment-build-plans/<osbp-id>/run`
- Input: Std headers, `String[] serverIds`

Basically, this call is used to run a build plan against a server, I am unable to figure out how to give the String array as input. All the calls in this appliance take only JSON as input and accept only JSON types. Any pointers as to what this might mean? Is it a JSON string? Is it an array of JSON objects?

Comment: see "JSON Arrays" here http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/. See instead JSON [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON)